# Multiple copies of the same EAR application on the same server with different URL and databases

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish, jax-ws

I have deployed a web service with Jax-ws that use a database for storing some state. I have packaged everything inside a EAR application and deployed it with Glassfish. I want to deploy multiple copies of this application on the same server (and then the same physical machine) but Glassfish does not allow it. Each application need to have a different WS endpoint (that is different url and/or port) and a different database so that each web service mantains its own state.

I tried deploying my application on different virtual servers and so different http listeners. So I got my application responding to different urls. Unfortunately the application is the same and so it is my database.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think glassfish will forbid deploying the same app more than once, if it has a different name.

The problem probably comes from the way the differentiating date is provisioned. The usual approach is to read these properties (for example - the database connection string, username, password) from an external source:

- external properties file
- JNDI
- (if exists) application-server-specific provisioning

However, you'd need a way to look for different files on the file system depending on the deployment. You can read the (web) context name on startup (from `ServletContext`) and look for:

```
 String path = System.getProperty("config.location") + "/" + ctx.getServletContextName();
```